# How to create a combobox supporting data virtualization in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, data-virtualization

I'm looking for a simple way to add data-virtualization support to WPF ComboBox?
How can I achieve that?

I tried to plug different collections to the ItemsSource property:
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization
- https://alphachitech.wordpress.com/2015/01/31/virtualizing-observable-collection

But seems my ComboBox is displaying nothing, am I doing something wrong?

Are they supposed to work with any controls supporting ItemsSource property?

Comment: Have you done some research?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst yes I did, I'm editing the post.

Comment: Thumb up for this improvement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `ItemsPanel` of the property to be a `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

```
<ComboBox VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```